# Pass data to liquid via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify, liquid

I want to make filter with ajax in shopify for my collection page.
So I have, ajax code that collects products from collection.products:

```
let allProducts = {{ collection.products | json }};
  $(".sidebar-btn").on("click", () => {
    allProducts.forEach(product => {
      jQuery.ajax({
                  url: '/products/'+product.handle,
                  dataType: 'json'
                })
                .done(function(data){
                  console.log(data.product.tags);
                  if(data.product.vendor !== "NATURECAN"){
                    console.log($(`.product-${data.product.id}`));
                  }
                });
    });
  });
```

And it filters the code, but the problem is that the products are already rendered to the DOM. What i want is to send the products that passed the filter back to the "include":

```
<ul class="grid grid--uniform{% if collection.products_count > 0 %} grid--view-items{% endif %}">

   
    {% for product in collection.products %}
        
      <li class="grid__item grid__item--{{section.id}} {{ grid_item_width }} product-{{product.id}}">
        {% include 'product-card-grid', max_height: max_height, product: product, show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor %}
      </li>
```

Is there are a way to do it. I can't use url for parameters,  so i must do it this way. thanks in advance.

(P.S. I am a bit new to shopify and liquid so i am sorry if the explanation wasn't as good)

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, I think you want to filter the products for a vendor, correct?
if yes, then you can direct this way listed into default [documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/collection#collection-current_vendor)

As per documentation, you can query the collections something like this `/collections/vendors?q=VENDOR`

[image]

Comment: No, i want to filter for vendor, product, price range a lot of things

Comment: then simply use any 3rd party app which provides you a better functionality.

Comment: No i must develop, the sidebar filter, myself, i have managed to make it work with liquid but i will need ajax for better functionality